# Extracting data from a table using selenium

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to extract data from a table that contains pagination using selenium but I have no idea how. The code below extracts the data correctly but I need all the data in the table and it only shows me the first 50. I think I should use selenium to be able to iterate over all the pages of the table so I can extract all the data. Do you have any idea how to do it? I would greatly appreciate your time.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "https://www.portfoliopersonal.com/Cotizaciones/Cedears"

# Send an HTTP request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find the table in the HTML (you may need to inspect the webpage to get the correct HTML structure)
    table = soup.find('table')

    # Check if the table was found
    if table:
        # Extract the table data
        table_data = []
        for row in table.find_all('tr'):
            row_data = [cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all(['td', 'th'])]
            table_data.append(row_data)

        # Save the table data to a CSV file
        with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            csv_writer.writerows(table_data)

        print("Table data saved to 'output.csv'")
    else:
        print("Table not found on the webpage.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve the webpage. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

Comment: How would you navigate to each page of data manually? You should use selenium to perform the exact same steps.

Answer (score 0):

As you use requests that gets the response correctly, which includes the data you need, you don't need to use selenium any more. You can use BS4 or others to get the json first by ID:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas` DataFrame to get the value from table and then save to csv.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_html("https://www.portfoliopersonal.com/Cotizaciones/Cedears")
print(df[0])
df[0].to_csv("path/to/filename")
```

**Output:**
[image]

**csv:**
[image]